# Setting a default value to a param attribute in the controller if it is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm enabling users to sort posts by `created_at` and `total_votes`:

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
@posts = current_user.subscribed_posts.paginate(:page => params[:page],
                                                :per_page => 5,
                                                :order => params[:order_by])
```

**show.html.erb:**

```
  <span class="comment-tab <% if params[:order_by] == 'created_at DESC' %>current-tab<% end %>"><%= link_to 'Date (DESC)', post_path(@post, :order_by => "created_at DESC") %></span>
  <span class="comment-tab <% if params[:order_by] == 'created_at ASC' %>current-tab<% end %>" ><%= link_to 'Date (ASC)', post_path(@post, :order_by => "created_at ASC") %></span>
  <span class="comment-tab <% if params[:order_by] == 'total_votes DESC' or params[:order_by].nil? %>current-tab<% end %>"><%= link_to 'Votes', post_path(@post, :order_by => "total_votes DESC") %></span>
```

I would like `:order_by` to have the value of `total_votes DESC` by default (when it is nil).

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the controller

```
params[:order_by] ||= "total_votes DESC"
```

Or

```
# fetch returns the default value if the key is not present
params.fetch(:order_by, "total_votes DESC")
```

[Hash#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-fetch)

Comment: Be careful with `||=` for setting defaults. `params[:my_bool] ||= true` will always be true, not true iff it's not defined.