# Passing params from select_tag to controller model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code on view,

```
<%=form_tag( '/price_verifications', method: "get", class: 'panel-body') do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%=select_tag :location, options_from_collection_for_select(Location.active_towns, :id, :name), prompt: "Select Location", class: 'form-control select2' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%=submit_tag "Filter", disable_with: 'Filtering...', class: 'btn btn-block btn-default' %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

When I choose one of the locations and click Filter, I would like to pass the selected location id, for example 44, to my controller:

```
def index 
   @missing_prices = Price.all_missing_prices(:id) 
end
```

My model:

```
   def self.all_missing_prices(id)
     missing_prices = Product.find_by_sql("
        SELECT * 
        FROM products
        WHERE status = 1
        AND id NOT IN (
          SELECT product_id
          FROM prices
          WHERE CAST(created_at as date) = CAST(curdate() as date)
          AND location_id = "+id.to_s+"
          )

      ")

  end
```

When I hard-code 44 as params in the controller, it works like charm.

Comment: Try `params[:location]`

Comment: Pavan, Thanks a million times. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value of location in the controller like below

```
params[:location] #will give the id selected in the drop-down
```

Comment: wait a minute..actually..after restarting the server..it gives a mysql error.."You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 9"

Comment: I got another input from this post..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695672/setting-a-default-value-to-a-param-attribute-in-the-controller-if-it-is-nil..which solved that new problem..thanks